# Flashing STM32F030 via uart bootloader under linux

Tags: microcontroller, arm, stm32

I'm going to evaluate STM32F030 microcontrollers (ARM) for replacement in one measuring device - and ordered a few already. Meanwhile I'm trying to collect info on how to work with them.

Currently I'm seeking for ways to flash them under Ubuntu - I want some console tool working via UART and built-in bootloader. I've found what seems to be an instruction with using OpenOCD, but I would be glad to hear about other utilities.

I need not debugging features, just to be able to flash a hex file to, probably, about a hundred devices... So the simpler - the better!

Comment: Setting up SWD is useful for development, but for the actual UART bootloader you might try http://sourceforge.net/projects/stm32flash/ though I've only used it with the F1 family and don't know if it supports the F0 parts out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

There is an Open Source Python serial bootloader which I have used with STM32F103.

It is described, along with a bug fix, at Pete Harrisons' [Micromouse Online](http://www.micromouseonline.com/2009/05/08/stm32-arm-cortex-bootloader/) web site. It gives links to the [original script](http://tuxotronic.org/wiki/projects/stm32loader) as well as his fixed version. You will need Python 2.6 or newer, but **not** Python 3. You'll also need the PySerial library.

It is command-line driven, so you can use it from the console and scripts.

If you decide to use ST Micro's Discovery or Nucleo boards for development, which include an ST-Link/V2, there is an Open Source loader for [STLink at by Texane at github](https://github.com/texane/stlink). It requires the Open Source libusb-1.0 library, but you may already have that installed.

It is also command-line driven.

The ST Nucleo development boards are also mbed's, so they have a nifty feature. They look like a USB flash drive to the host OS, and copying a file to the drive programs the target MCU. So these don't need any extra host software for upload.